# Overwrite has_many getter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following model:

```
class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  has_many key_phrases
end
```

And I want to create a method that overwrites the getter `key_phrases`, something like:

```
class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  has_many key_phrases

  def key_phrases
    # if current value is not an empty array, return, otherwise creates, something like:
    current_value = super()
    return current_value unless current_value.nil?

    get_key_phrases.each do |k|
      key_phrases.create(k)
    end
    return key_phrases
  end
end
```

I know what I want to do, but because I lack knowledge about Ruby and Rails, I don't know exactly how to code that.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that leads you to want to override the association? My hunch is that there's a better way to solve the original problem.

Comment: Have you considered doing a callback on create to create your `key_phrases`?

Comment: @JoshBrody not really. Can I create a hook that would be called on create?

Comment: Sure can. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html :)

Comment: @jvillian isn't that just a facilitator?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure if I follow you when you say I'm duplicating key phrases. I'm not. I have a model called `Metric` that has a lot of metrics, including key_phrases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you can add an alias to make sure the rest of the code doesn't break. The idea is to rename your existing `has_many` method to something else and use the existing  `key_phrases` as a normal method.

This way you don't have to change anywhere else in the codebase and this will work with minimum changes.

[Read more here about alias_attribute](https://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_attribute)

```rb
class Metric < ApplicationRecord

  alias_attribute :phrases, :key_phrases #NOTE the alias_attribute should be before `key_phrases`
  has_many key_phrases

  def key_phrases
    # your logic goes into this method
    if phrases.empty?
      # create
    else
      phrases
    end
  end 
end
```

However... I personally create a more meaning full method and leave the "has_many key_phrases" as it is, the reason is, this implies and gets and if you are trying to create records in the same method it's a bit confusing.

So, I would do something like this

```rb
class Metric < ApplicationRecord

  has_many key_phrases

  def get_or_create_key_phrases(*params)
    if phrases.empty?
      # create
    else
      phrases
    end
  end 
end
```

and then change all the places that call `key_phrases` to `get_or_create_key_phrases`, which I personally think more explicit. But as per the downside, you'll have to change more places in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overwriting the getter method for `key_phrases`, you could instead write a callback that creates `key_phrases` for the `Metric` object after it is created.

```
def Metric < ApplicationRecord
  has_many key_phrases

  after_create do |metric|
    get_key_phrases.each do |phrase|
      metric.key_phrases.create(phrase)
    end
  end
end
```